# jquery cycle to vertically scroll through table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay I have a table that I am populating with 25 rows of information. I want to use Jquery cycle or something similar to create a vertical scrolling effect, so the rows constantly scroll vertically upwards through a container that can display roughly five rows at a time.

I have used jquery cycle for numerous things, but for some reason I am at a dead end on trying to get it to work for a table.

I think my confusion is probably on how I need to set up my table/container structurally so cycle knows what children or elements to apply to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#table_container').cycle({ //Will this even work for a table???
          fx:'scrollVert', 
                  continuous: 1 
      });
});
```

So how do I structure the table elements so cycle influences them?

More on [Jquery Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), from their website:

The plugin provides a method called cycle which is invoked on a container element. Each child element of the container becomes a "slide". Options control how and when the slides are transitioned.

Comment: My confusion is what jquery cycle is.. some examples or references would be nice next time :) I would also recommend not using tables for this kind of stuff.

Comment: yes, the table is already coded and laid out so I suppose I am trying to work with that to save time, but redoing it in a div format would certainly be a good idea. Also, short jquery cycle explanation added to OP.

Answer (score 2):

The cycle call function works on the children sections. For table before tr generally tbody tab is created.. Try with the below. it works fine..

Html - `<table id="table_container">
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>4</td></tr>
        <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    </table>`

Css -  `#table_container, #table_container tbody  {
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid red;
            display: block;
            width: 100px;
            position: relative;
            overflow: hidden; 
        }
        #table_container tr{
            display:block;
            height: 100px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            width: 100px;
        }`

jquery - `$("#table_container tbody").cycle({
            fx: "scrollDown"

        });`

Try with this one.

If you want to show multi rows at time then segregate multi rows with some logical separator  so that that section can be iterated instead of tr.